# How do I make a ListView stretch to fill the height of a column in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have a `ListView` control. I want to make it stretch to fill the entire length of a column. To achieve this, I set the `ColumnDefinition` to `"*"`. I set the `ListView`'s `VerticalAlignment` property to `Stretch`, both for the `ListView` and for its containing elements.

Currently, the `ListView` will only increase in size when data is shown inside of it.

How do I make the `ListView` stretch to the size of the column no matter what data is shown inside it?

Here is a sample version of my XAML file. It shows that the `VerticalAllignment` is set to stretch on the `ListView` and all of the containing elements:

```xml
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Main" 
                    Margin="1,-1,-2,1">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" >

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Border BorderBrush="Black" 
                        BorderThickness=".5" 
                        Padding="4"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >

                        <ListView x:Name="FilesDisplayed"  
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding AllFilePaths}" 
                                    SelectionChanged="FilesDisplayed_SelectionChanged" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using `StackPanel` when you want inner elements to fill the outer space. Replace it with `Grid` and use `Grid.ColumnDefinitions` or `Grid.RowDefinitions` to adjust the location.

Comment: This was the solution, thank you. Do you know why `Grid` is preferred over `StackPanel` in this context?

Comment: In my understanding, in the case of `Grid`, the layout primarily depends on the size of outer surrounding element and inner matrix sizes. In contrast, in the case of `StackPanel`, the layout depends on the sizes of inner elements.